# Uncaught ReferenceError: imageCrop is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, crop, codepen

I am trying to upload and crop a image in a bootstrap modal and I followed [codepen example](https://codepen.io/joshhunt18/pen/NPKEzQ). I didn't import any cropping library except jquery, bootstrap etc. I am getting error ,

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: imageCrop is not defined
>       at cropImage (upload-image.js?v=20180410173156:55)
>       at Image.img.onload (upload-image.js?v=20180410173156:41)"

Any library should I use or any javascript I want to write? I am new to javascript

My Javascript :

```
$('#drop').on('click', function() {
    $('#fileUpload').trigger('click');
});

$('#fileUpload').on('change', function(e) {
    addImage(e.target);
});

$("#drop").on("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('dragging');
});

$("#drop").on("dragleave", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('dragging');
});

$("#drop").on("drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var data = e.dataTransfer || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    addImage(data);
});

function addImage(data) {
    var file = data.files[0];
    if (file.type.indexOf('image') === -1) {
        alert('Sorry, the file you uploaded doesn\'t appear to be an image.');
        return false;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            if (img.width < 200 || img.height < 200) {
                alert('Sorry, the image you uploaded doesn\'t appear to be large enough.');
                return false;
            }
            cropImage(img);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function cropImage(originalImage) {

    $(originalImage).attr('id', 'fullImage');
    $('#imageResize').html(originalImage);
    // $('#sectionDragAndDrop').addClass('hidden');
    $('#sectionResize').removeClass('hidden');

    var newImage = new imageCrop('#fullImage', 200, 200);

    $('#crop').on('click', function() {
        var results = newImage.crop();
        $('#thumbnail').html(results.img);
        // $('#sectionResize').addClass('hidden');
        $('#sectionThumbnail').removeClass('hidden');
    });

}
```

Comment: Your codepen works

Comment: Yes this codepen example works. but in mine crop function is not working and displays Uncaught reference error in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `imageCrop` definition, following your codepen link , you will find the script in JS setting, in the external scripts : [ImageCrop](https://codepen.io/joshhunt18/pen/dtpzw).

Comment: Dang beat me to it. +1 =)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I couldn't fint that there's any link there except jquery library (//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js)

Comment: under the jquery library, there is another one : (https://codepen.io/joshhunt18/pen/dtpzw) which contains the `imageCrop` definition.

Comment: I can't get that. I see empty field under the jquery library(//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js)
Can you please put here the library link?
Thanks in advance

Comment: here is the link : https://codepen.io/joshhunt18/pen/dtpzw, you have to copy the function definition and include it in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the idea. Thanks in advance